# Please show me what's going wrong with this delete row function for SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to learn the basics of making databases in Visual C#, and I am building a basic application.  In the application there is a delete button that will delete the record that is currently shown in the textboxes.  The code I have at the moment is this:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentRow.Delete();
    dAdapter.Update(dataset, "Contacts");
    clearTextBoxes();
}
```

currentRow is the DataRow I want to delete and that which is shown in the textboxes.  dataset is the Dataset.  dAdapter is the DataAdapter, and "Contacts" is the table name or w/e.  However this is generating an error sometimes.  What's wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Letting us in on what the error is would go a long way

Comment: Upon trying to run the program, I get a message:  InvalidOperationException was Unhandled:  Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the `dAdapter.DeleteCommand` property?  Based on the error message, it sounds like this property might not be set or may be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to outline a delete command, something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dAdapter" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Sheep] WHERE Id = @Id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@Id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```